# Inform end user with proper message based on the status code

Tags: swift

I am trying to inform user with a custom message as follows based on the HTTPURLResponse statusCode. However in the following implementation, I am having issue with StatusCode enum which is not properly implemented, I wonder how to fix that issue.

And also I wonder how to come up with a better approach to this type of generic issues?

```
enum StatusCode: Int, RawRepresentable {
  case 400 = "It is a bad Request"
  case 401 = "You are unauthorized"
  case 403 = "You are forbidden"
  case 404 = "Your request is not found, please try again"
}


func errorCheck(statusCode:Int){
    if statusCode == StatusCode.400 {
       print(StatusCode.400.rawValue)
    }else if statusCode == StatusCode.404 {
       print(StatusCode.404.rawValue)
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't think identifiers can start with a digit, i.e. `case 400` isn't syntatically legal

Comment: @NewDev What is your suggestion to handle this type of feature?

Comment: You want to translate a specific HTTP error code to a string? You could create a computed property `description` (or something) that has a `switch` and returns the correct string depending on the enum value

Comment: @NewDev, could you please illustrate your example?

Comment: I guess I'm not fully understanding what you're trying to achieve... how is `errorCheck` meant to be used? What happens if the status code doesn't map to what's defined in the enum?

Comment: errorCheck method will be called if httpstatuscode is equal or bigger than 300, then I need to inform user with custom message. if enum does not cover, than very generic message such as "An unknown error ......"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What I think you're to do can be accomplished like so:

```
enum StatusCode: Int, RawRepresentable, CustomStringConvertible {
    case e400 = 400
    case e401 = 401
    case e403 = 403
    case e404 = 404
    
    var description: String {
        switch self {
        case .e400: return "It is a bad Request"
        case .e401: return "You are unauthorized"
        case .e403: return "You are forbidden"
        case .e404: return "Your request is not found, please try again"
        }
    }
}
```

Then you could use it like this:

```
func errorCheck(code: Int){
    if let statusCode = StatusCode(rawValue: code) {
       print(statusCode)
    } else {
       print("An unknown error ......")
    }
}
```